# what are the maximum length of PHP variable/function/class name?

Tags: php, class, function, variables

Please if you know, make a response.
thanks

Comment: I'm sure it's longer than anyone would ever want it to be, but you can always check the sources to find out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I couldn't find an answer but this

http://www.php.net/manual/en/userlandnaming.php

Says

> However, there are some pretty sexy
>   characters in there should you be
>   looking for a unique namespace which
>   is not too lengthy

I think if you're worried about being too long for the compiler, it's way too long for a human.